# How to Load PowerShell Functions On-Demand?

Tags: powershell, include, powershell-module

In my personal PowerShell profile that loads whenever I start PowerShell, I want to include a set of functions by calling a function.

So I want to do something like this:

```
function loadMyFunctions{
    . \MyFunctions.ps1
}
```

Now, in `MyFunctions.ps1` I have a function:

```
function bobtest{
    write-host "My name is Bob Newhart."
}
```

I am able to load the script MyFunctions.ps1, but after that is loaded I am not able to call `bobtest` in the console - I get the error message `The term bobtest is not recognized...`

However, if I just load the script outside the function then that script is loaded and I can call `bobtest` normally - but that means that I can't just not load `MyFunctions` when the profile is loaded - I *have* to load `MyFunctions` and cannot choose.

You see, I want to load the other functions on demand and not have them available until I choose.

Is there another way to do this or can it even be done?

Comment: That's interesting - I thought briefly about modules and then forgot about it - I'll try and figure out how to do that.

Comment: Sorry accidentally deleted that comment. Modules are a pretty good way to go! I have used those in the past rather than using functions. Never had an issue with those. Using the profile to call a module with other functions inside it. I have delete the previous answer as i agree i interpreted the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [page](http://mikefrobbins.com/2013/07/04/how-to-create-powershell-script-modules-and-module-manifests/), How to Create PowerShell Modules and Manifests.

This will enable you to create a module which will have all your custom functions! Then inside of your `loadMyFunctions` cmdlet add `Import-Module NewModuleName`.

This will enable you to use your cmdlets.

Hope this Helps,
Lachlan

Comment: This works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the good idea.

Comment: Much to kind, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use modules. But still if you want to get in some different ways , then you can try with your approach.

See the below screenshots which I have performed.

I have a function **addition** which simply does addition and I saved it as *funct1.ps1*

Now I am calling the same function from another function of the other script just using dot source without using as module and it results me properly.

**Funct1.ps1**

[image]

**Triggered the function** from another function in another script .

[image]

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: That's a reasonable approach too.  I know that a function can dotsource a script and use its functions, but what I really wanted was a way to "include" a script on the fly by choice.